# Java: ProcessBuilder: Running Java Files

Tags: java, processbuilder

Does another user need the Java Development Kit to execute a Java file with the following code?

```
try {
   ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar", "ColorPickerFrame.jar");
   ProcessBuilder inheritIO = pb.inheritIO();
   Process p = pb.start();
} catch (IOException ex) {}
```

Because it contanins the `java -jar File.jar` statement.

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they simply need *any* `java` command on their path. The OS sees this as:

```
java -jar ColorPickerFrame.jar
```

and calls any `java` on the path. In most cases, a JRE will be on the path if not the JDK, so it should work. And you must remember that even via the JDK, a private *JRE* is used.